# a word or short phrase that can stand for "a book, play, or film/movie"

Tags: phrase-request

In Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary, the first definition of the word **dialogue** is as follows.

> conversations in **a book, play, or film/movie**

In that specific dictionary, the phrase, **a book, play, or film/movie** is used a lot to describe many words' definitions.

As it seems that a book, play, or film/movie all share some quality in their nature, I've thought that the phrase can be substituted by other expressions.

What I came up with are as follows.

1. conversations in **art**
2. conversations in **a piece of art or literature**
3. conversations in **a produced content with imaginary characters in it**

I would like to ask you how correct those are and ask for your guides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suggestion are close, but might be misleading to a native speaker.
**Art**, on its own, most usually means painting, drawing, sculpture and similar -- things which don't have dialogue.  ("Conversations in art" could easily be understood as meaning Picasso and Matisse "conversing" through their paintings.)  **Produced content** would not have a specific meaning without more context.

To includes novels, films and plays we would be much more likely to say

- **... in a work of fiction**
- **... in any kind of fiction**

You'll notice your original definition includes "book", which doesn't necessarily mean a work of fiction -- many biographies have dialogue in them.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. And I understood the use of the word **fiction** would be very useful. Then how about using **in a production** or **in a fictional production**? I think **a production** might be also as abstract as **produced content**,  but I, also, would like to know if there is any difference between **in a production** and **in produced content** there. I am sorry for asking you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The alternatives you have suggested are too abstract. One definition of "dialog" **IS** a conversation within the context of a book, play, or movie. That is very clear. The other three phrases are not as easily understood. Always strive for clarity, not ambiguity.

Comment: Thank you for such good advice and answering.